# Cannot make JSON text out of javascript object

Tags: javascript, json

I'd like to convert this object that I receive from server to a JSON file so that I can use it in d3.js  chart:

```
data = {
   "dog ":"5",
   "cat ":"4",
   "fish ":"12",
}
```

The output should be:

```
{    
    "name" : "animal",
    "children" : [
        {"name":"dog", "value": 5},
        {"name":"cat", "value": 4},
        {"name":"fish", "value": 10}
    ]
}
```

What I came up with is:

```
   var jsonText = [] ;
   for ( key in data) {
  jsonText.push({name : key.trim(), value : parseInt(data[key])});
 }
```

But when I try to print out the object, I receive:

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

In addition to that I have no clue how to add other attributes to the JSON file. So appreciate your hints.

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(object));`

Comment: @CertainPerformance sorry, I corrected the typo.

Comment: Where are you getting the `name:animal` data from? The data I'm seeing from your snippet never tells you that.

Comment: @OscarGodson True. that's part of the problem. I have no clue how to add it to the json from the javascript object.

Comment: Well, I mean, where does the word "animal" come from?

Comment: @JabariDash Thanks for the tip. But I still need to add parent `name` and `children` to the JSON

Comment: @OscarGodson I just need to insert `animal` to the output JSON, so that it can be used by d3.js in drawing chart. It does not come from the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys(data)` and loop through the `key` to get the desired object structure.

```js
var data = {
 "dog ":"5",
 "cat ":"4",
 "fish ":"12",
};
var res = {
  name: "animal",
  children: []
};
Object.keys(data).forEach((key)=>{
  res.children.push(
   {name:key.trim(), value: parseInt(data[key])}
  );
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Why not simply use `for (key in data)`? As a bonus, that would also work for non-enumerable objects.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're manually adding a key like `animal` this should work and the values should be ints.

```js
var data = {
   "dog ":"5",
   "cat ":"4",
   "fish ":"12",
}

var children = Object.keys(data).map((key) => {
  return {
    name: key.trim(),
    value: parseInt(data[key])
  }
})

let result = JSON.stringify({
  name: 'animal',
  children
})

console.log(result);
```

That will return

```
{"name":"animal","children":[{"name":"dog ","value":5},{"name":"cat ","value":4},{"name":"fish ","value":12}]}
```

Comment: @Babr how about this?

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there (the array is formatted correctly), but you need the resulting array to be the value of the `children` property of the object. It would also be a bit easier to use `Object.entries` and `map`, which tranforms an array into another array based on the same elements:

```js
const data = {
   "dog ":"5",
   "cat ":"4",
   "fish ":"12",
};
const children = Object.entries(data)
  .map(([name, value]) => ({ name: name.trim(), value: Number(value) }));
const output = { name: 'animal', children };
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Nice! Just need the values to be `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Try - `console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonText))`

Answer (score 1):

Create an object with `children` key and  push value to it

```js
let data = {
  "dog ": "5",
  "cat ": "4",
  "fish ": "12",
}

let newObj = {
  "name": "animal",
  "children": []
}
for (let keys in data) {
  newObj.children.push({
    name: keys.trim(),
    value: parseInt(data[keys], 10)
  });
}
console.log(newObj)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just iterate over the `data` object using `for..in` and push `prop: value` pair objects into you `children` array:

```js
const data = {
   "dog ": "5",
   "cat ": "4",
   "fish ": "12",
}

let obj = {
  name: "animal",
  children: []
}

for (prop in data) {
  let animal = {}
  animal[prop.trim()] = Number(data[prop])
  obj.children.push(animal)
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

```
    const data = {
       "dog ":"5",
       "cat ":"4",
       "fish ":"12",
    }

    Object.keys(data).reduce((obj, animal) => ({
      ...obj,
      children: [
          ...obj.children,
          {
              name: animal,
              value: data[animal]
          }
      ]
    }), {name: "animal", children: []})

    console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

This is a cleaner way to get the desired results in my opinion